# Interior mapping shader doesn't follow object rotation

Tags: shader-nodes

I'm trying to create an interior mapping shader using blender.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/9CQLftRp1QQ).
The problem I'm having is that it only works using plane oriented in one direction.

[image: the result with a rotated image]

I've tried using the normal of the geometry but with no success.

[This shader](https://meeww.gumroad.com/l/rmkdsz) uses the actual rotation of the object, but this causes an issue with multiple objects using the same shader, and rotating the object 'cut' the projection.

[image: said shader with rotated plane, you can see the projection beeing cut]

Here is my blend file:
[image]

How can I make it so the shader works in any rotation (around the z axis), and not cut the projection ?